# How to calculate Time difference based on conditions i.e different strings and new date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to solve this problem but I cannot think of a formula to do in Excel.

| Date | Time | Photographer | TimeWorked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:17:00 AM | alizée16 | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:23:00 AM | alondra | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 4:38:00 PM | alondra | 21 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:17:00 PM | alondra | 54 |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:21:00 AM | aman | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:22:00 AM | aman | 1 |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:58:00 AM | aman | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:38:00 AM | amelia | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:43:00 AM | amelia | 5 |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:47:00 AM | amelia | 4 |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:54:00 AM | amelia | 7 |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:55:00 AM | amelia | 1 |
| 04/09/2021 | 6:57:00 AM | amelia | 2 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:12:00 AM | amelia | 15 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:15:00 AM | amelia | 3 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:20:00 AM | amelia | 5 |
| 04/09/2021 | 7:28:00 AM | amelia | 8 |
| 04/09/2021 | 9:45:00 AM | amelia | #NUM! |
| 04/09/2021 | 11:44:00 AM | amelia | 59 |
| 12/09/2021 | 7:33:00 AM | amelia | 5 |
| 12/09/2021 | 8:16:00 AM | amelia | 43 |
| 12/09/2021 | 8:22:00 AM | amelia | 6 |
| 12/09/2021 | 8:25:00 AM | amelia | 3 |

I want to calculate TimeWorked in minutes which is calculated by b3-b2, b4-b3,b5-b4 and so on. I have currently used MINUTE(b3-b2) formula.

But desired result is not so simple. I want to differentiate it on the basis of date and photographer as well i.e If the date or photographer or (data and photographer) both changes, then I again want to start from 0.

e.g In row 21, as date changes from 04/09 to 12/09 a new day starts so for the row 21, Time Worked will be 0.

In the same way in row 5 as the photographer changes from 'Alondra' to 'Aman' Time Worked for Aman in tow 5 will be 0.

The general idea of formula in Time Worked Table will be

= Minutes( Date(Row 3) - Date (Row 2)) but date or photographer changes, time worked will be set to 0 and again start calculations from there.

I would have done it manually but the table contains 13K rows so doing it manually will take a lot of time.

If it doesn't work in Excel, we can do it in Python or SQL as well and export it back as csv but I a newbie in both so I will need help with Python and SQL code as well.

Comment: the sorting is not correct, how can the finish time be less than the start time for the same date and photographer?

Comment: @ScottCraner I have fixed the sorting. Please help!

Comment: @ScottCraner Thankyou so much for the answer

Comment: ^^^^Îf Scott's answer is correct, then please mark it as such, that way everyone will know your problem is solved

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IF with AND to test the photographer and DATE, if they match do the math otherwise return `0`.

```
=IF(AND(C2=C1,A2=A1),B2-B1,0)
```

Then format the output as `[mm]`

[image]